# GIT | Set default branch using org.kohsuke java API

Tags: github, groovy, github-api

I was exploring org.kohsuke java API to perform git operations.I could create the git repo successfully and created a branch as well. But I am not finding a way to set the branch I created as a default branch in GIT using java API. Can someone assist me on this. Please find the code snippet below

```
GHOrganization organization = github.getOrganization(organizationName)
Map<String,GHTeam> teams = organization.teams
GHRepository repo = organization.createRepository repoName, null, null, teams.'Backend-developers', true

GHContentUpdateResponse commitResponse = repo.createContent "Read me for "+repoName, "Readm me for "+repoName, "README.md"
repo.createRef("refs/heads/testbranch", commitResponse.getCommit().getSHA1()) //creating test branch here which is working.
//But below line doesn't work
repo.setDefaultBranch "refs/heads/testbranch"
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have exactly the right idea; it does appear as though your original snippet is missing parentheses.
That said,

`repo.setDefaultBranch("branch-name");`

is correct for kohsuke's Github API 1.76 (and later); I do not know if it worked in versions prior to that.

Additionally, it is possible that your code to create the branch is not working as expected. Does the branch appear in GitHub?